# CSS: How is the hamburger icon generated in this plugin?

Tags: css, icons

Am a little confused on how exactly the hamburger icon is generated in this 3rd party [**CSS snippet**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/3fo47n21/). In my own work, how I go about it is I include a png of the icon through `background: url`, but I've gone through this snippet here many times and can't figure how the 'icon' has been invoked.

Would appreciate any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a background image - the hamburger ion is created using the :before and :after css pseudo selectors:

```
.menu-opener-inner::before, .menu-opener-inner::after {
   background: white;
   content: '';
   display: block;
   height: .5rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
 }
```

Basically the .menu-opener-inner is set as a white horizontal bar that is .5 rem high and 2.5 rem wide. Then there is another bar created before andafter it using the pseudoselectors.

When it is active, it is transparent and the pseudo stripes are rotated 45 degrees. All with CSS - gotta luv it